Confusion about Mathematical Induction
Recently I am studying calculus. There is a conclusion:
$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}b_n=0\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(a_n+b_n)=0$
It is easy to prove that this can be promoted to finite summations. But for infinite summations it could be wrong. For example,
$\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(n\cdot\frac{1}{n})=1$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2})=0$.
Now here comes my question. What if I use Mathematical Induction (MI) to prove this wrong problem?
Let's make this clear. Say we have $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}a_n=0$, try prove $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}na_n=0$ (!of course wrong) using MI.

for $n=1$, obvious $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}1\cdot a_n=0$.
Suppose for $n=k$, $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}k\cdot a_n=0$ (We know this is wrong when k=n)
$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N_1>0,s.t. n>N,|ka_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ (this is wrong either, but we write it according to hypothesis)
$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N_2>0,s.t. n>N,|a_n|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$
Let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$,we get $|(k+1)a_n|<\varepsilon$,which shows $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(k+1)\cdot a_n=0$.

But which part on earth cause the error?

If hypothesis of $n=k$ is wrong, how could I judge that ? This is the base step of MI, for many problems I just cannot easily tell it is wrong (just as $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}(n\cdot\frac{1}{n})=1$)

If it is because I tried to use MI on a limit problem, which is actually a infinite problem, I may ask when MI is valid ? And why my example goes wrong ?


Can anyone help me? It really bothers me a lot.

One issue is that exchanging limits often does not work.  For example $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{a \to 0^+} na \not = \lim\limits_{a \to 0^+} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} na $ where $a>0$ since the left hand side is $0$ and the right hand side is $+\infty$.

Use \to to get $\to$ instead of using ->

@jjagmath. I fixed it, but hopefully he learns for the future.

A fundamental misunderstanding you seem to have is that in an expression like $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ there is a value of $n$ that you can fix. There is not: the name $n$ is a dummy variable bound by the $\lim$ symbol (it could be systematically replaced by another name without changing the meaning or the value), and undefined outside its scope. The expression (if well defined for a given sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$) designates just a one number, there is nothing to fix.

Your induction is not wrong. Actually, what you have proved is the following claim:
For any integer $m\in \mathbb{N}$. If $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=0,$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}ma_n=0$.
Here $m$ is a fixed number.

I got it. But there comes another question. For every fixed $m\in\mathbb{N}$,we see it is a finite summation (forgive me using natural language, I don't know how to precisely express it in mathematical languate). How comes that infinite summation just failes ? We say for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$ it is true, but when $m\to+\infty$, something goes wrong? Thanks a lot for your help!

@HenryXie Your induction just proved the claim I mentioned. For $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}na_n$, you have come up with two examples with different limits, thus not true. For what you have done, you just fix that number $m$ without letting it tends to infinity. Thus, your induction does not work for $m\to \infty$ as $\infty$ is not a integer.

@HenryXie Even though by induction, $m$ can be $10^{100000}$(very large), but it is still an integer, right? It cannot be infinity.

Yeah, I totally got it. If we use notation $m$, for $N$ we can get a quite large range than $m$. But for notation $n$ as $na_n$, the move speed must be the same, which causes different result. Thank you ~

@HenryXie You are welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it helps.

The issue is that you're working with statements that do not depend on $n$. In fact, you're not working with staments (one for each value of $n$), just one single statement about how a sequence whose members depend on $n$ behaves. You can't substitute a concrete number for the variable $n$ in the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=0$. What would $\lim_{75\to\infty}75a_{75}=0$ even mean? The reason is that on the left side the variable $n$ is just there to signify that we're looking at all the members of the sequence $na_n$ at once and calculate a number from all of them, in this case their limit. If that number contains variables, like $\lim_{n\to\infty}k+\frac1n=k$, feel free to substitute things for $k$. But if it's something like $0$, where would you even substitute whatever you're trying to substitute?
There are many similar operators which do not allow us to just substitute a number for a variable for the same reasons. Here is an incomplete collection of examples:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$, see above.
$\sum_{n=1}^3 n$. It's a number, specifically $6$. Substituting, say, 2, for $n$ makes no sense. What's $\sum_{2=1}^3 2$ supposed to mean?
$\max_{n\in\mathbb N^+}\frac1n$. It's $1$, nothing to substitute here.
$\inf_{n\in\mathbb N^+}\frac1n$. It's $0$, nothing to substitute.
$\bigcap_{x\in[0,\infty)}[0,x]$. It's $\{0\}$, a set, not a number, but still nothing to substitute here.

So your error is this: You substituted numbers for a variable which is just a "dummy", so to speak, and does not allow substitution.

You have proved that for all natural $k$, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} k \cdot a_n = 0$ - this is true. The problem is that you can't substitute $k = n$, as $n$ is bound in this formula.
If you write definition of $\lim$, you proved $\forall k \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N_0 \forall n > N_0: |k \cdot a_n| < \epsilon$. But you can't switch order of quantifiers over $k$ and $n$ to get $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N_0 \forall n > N_0 \forall k: |k \cdot a_n| < \epsilon$ (and from this you would be able to get $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N_0 \forall n > N_0: |n \cdot a_n| < \epsilon$).
Similar example: we know, that for any (real) $y \neq 0$, equation $xy = -1$ has non-zero (real) solution. However, we can't substitute $y = x$ to deduce that equation $x^2 = -1$ has (real) solution.
